# Javascript lost context when assigned to other variable

Tags: javascript, this

Why in javascript if you reference objects method to some variable it loses that objects context. Can't find any link with explanation what happens under the hood. Except this one which states:
  [‘this’ refers to the object which ‘owns’ the method](http://www.sitepoint.com/what-is-this-in-javascript/) which doesn't seam to be true.

```
var Class = function() {
    this.property = 1
}

Class.prototype.method = function() {
    return this.property;
}

var obj = new Class();
console.log(obj.method() === 1);

var refToMethod = obj.method; // why refToMethod 'this' is window


console.log(refToMethod() !== 1) // why this is true?

var property = 1;
console.log(refToMethod() === 1)
```

Comment: `refToMethod` is bound to the context of window. You need to pass the context to the call: `refToMethod.call(obj)` or `refToMethod.apply(obj)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how a function is called. If a function is not referenced through being an attribute of an object (e.g. `refToMethod`) then it will be assigned the "Global context" which is `window`. However, when a function is an attribute of object (e.g. `obj.method`), we refer to it as a method, and it is implicitly assigned the context of it's parent object.

JavaScript's context is unlike many languages in that you can override it easily using either [`.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply). Furthermore, ECMAScript 5 introduced a new [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method to allow you to create copies of methods which are always bound to the same context. [***See MDN for more***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

```
var obj = new Class();
obj.method(); // 1;

var unbound = obj.method;
unbound(); // undefined;

// Call and Apply setting the context to obj.
unbound.apply(obj); // 1
unbound.call(obj); // 1;

// ECMAScript 5's bind
var bound = unbound.bind(obj);
bound(); // 1;
```

Comment: Wait, your second comment is a bit confusing to me. Isn't the context (this) of an object's member function lost when it is passed to another function like "obj.method"? Like if I called setTimeout(obj.method, 300); wouldn't this=undefined still? We'd still need to bind like setTimeout(obj.method(obj), 300), no?

Answer (score 3):

From Douglas Crockford's book [JavaScript: The Good Parts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742)

> The this parameter is very important in object oriented programming,
>   and its value is determined by the invocation pattern. There are four
>   patterns of invocation in JavaScript: the method invocation pattern,
>   the function invocation pattern, the constructor invocation pattern,
>   and the apply invocation pattern. The patterns differ in how the bonus
>   parameter this is initialized

**The Method Invocation Pattern**

> When a function is stored as a property of an object, we call it a
>   method. When a method is invoked, this is bound to that object. If an
>   invocation expression contains a refinement (that is, a . dot
>   expression or[subscript] expression), it is invoked as a method

In your example method invocation pattern is

```
console.log(obj.method() === 1);
```

and this in this case is bound to the object "Class" and it works as you expected.

**The Function Invocation Pattern**

> When a function is not the property of an object, then it is invoked
>   as a function:
>
> var sum = add(3, 4); // sum is 7
>
> When a function is invoked with this pattern, this is bound to the
>   global object. This was a mistake in the design of the language. Had
>   the language been designed correctly, when the inner function is
>   invoked, this would still be bound to the this variable of the outer
>   function. A consequence of this error is that a method cannot employ
>   an inner function to help it do its work because the inner function
>   does not share the method’s access to the object as its this is bound
>   to the wrong value

In your case

```
var refToMethod = obj.method; // why refToMethod 'this' is window
console.log(refToMethod() !== 1) // why this is true?
```

refToMethod is bound to the global object "window" in this case

You can find more information about this at [JavaScript “this” keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword)

Answer (score 0):

Because you only assigned the function `method` to the `refToMethod`. When it runs the context is `window`.

Answer (score 0):

It becomes clear when you print the object and the reference to the function:

```
console.log(obj); // Prints -> Class {property: 1, method: function}

console.log(refToMethod);
// Prints 
// function () {
//    return this.property;
// }
```

In the context of the `obj`, what is `this`? It is the `Class` object, that has an attribute called `property`.

And what is `this` in the context of the `refToMethod`? It is the `window` object. Thats why your assert failed the first time and it is true the second time. When you declare:

```
var property = 1;
```

You are actually declaring an attribute to the `window` object.