# How to bind a method to original context when assigned to variable

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, this

Since functions are given "global context" when not accessed as a property of an object [1], the following has the same quirk:

```
const foo = ({bar}) => {
  bar(); // this === window
}
```

because it's just syntactic sugar for:

```
const foo = (x) => {
  var bar = x.bar;
  bar();
}
```

which seems slightly counter-intuitive to me since I now have to re-bind or forgo the sugar.

Is there a way to change this behaviour so that the context isn't changed (besides explicitly setting it via .apply/call/bind)? Are there any plans/proposals for standards to be implemented for it?

[1] [Javascript lost context when assigned to other variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23154778/javascript-lost-context-when-assigned-to-other-variable?rq=1)

Comment: There is a proposal for something relevant https://github.com/zenparsing/es-function-bind but it's stage-0.

Comment: That's not a quirk, that's an integral part of the language design. The sugar is there to make things easier for you, not to do the thinking. When passing a callback-function, it's unusual that it needs to be called in a specific context. Even if it's passed as a property (named "bar" or maybe "success"/"fail") on some config-object. 
On the other hand, if you pass an instance of some class, and need to call a method on that instance, well that's a totally different approach/use-case. And it's up to you to implement either one or the other. This sugar just helps at implementing the former

Comment: What do you want `this` to be?

Comment: @zerkms: The suggestions to integrate the `::` operator in destructuring were dropped however.

Comment: @aray12 For the context for `bar` to be `x`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you answered your own question. If you are taking an Object as argument, then any function you pass as a property will already be a method, thus loosing context, regardless of what the syntax looks like.

What you can do is call the bound function from inside the argument's method:

```
const argumentContainingBar = {
  bar: () => { originallyBoundFunction() }
}
```

Now you can `foo(argumentContainingBar)` without loosing context.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `call`/`apply`, then your only choice is not to assign the property to a variable.

Seriously, don't use destructuring for methods. It wasn't made for that.

> Are there any plans/proposals for standards to be implemented for it?

There was a [suggestion in the function-bind proposal](https://github.com/zenparsing/es-function-bind/issues/5), but it was not pursued further.

Comment: `function foo({ ::doA, ::doC }) {` --- woah, with such a pace in 3 years ES will take over haskell in terms of number of "funny" characters/constructs used in the language.

Comment: @zerkms: That might be one reason why it's been dropped :-)