# How to keep function context when given as a parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, this

When copying a `this.xxx` function, it seems that some kind of context is lost.

In the following example, the call to `this.post` works fine, but the `postCopy` leads to an error.

```js
class MyClass {
  
  myFunc(){
    await this.post(...) // works fine

    const postCopy = this.post
    await postCopy(...) // does not work properly
  }
}
```

I don't understand what is the difference between the two calls since `postCopy === this.post` => `true`.

My final goal is to take `this.post` as an argument for `myFunc`, how could I achieve having the `postCopy` work properly ?

Although this question has been marked as duplicate, I think it is not. This question is about "what to do when I encounter this situation", not a general question about "how does the `this` keyword works in javascript", which will be found by people who encounter this same problem.

Comment: `const postCopy = this.post.bind(this)`

Answer (score -2):

When calling a named function, (const / let / parameter), the `this` context is not passed, unless you use `postCopy.call(this, ...args)`.

Comment: Which details does this answer contain that are missing in https://stackoverflow.com/a/23154981/16540390

Comment: It's the same answer, but the question is different. The question  int stackoverflow.com/a/23154981/16540390 is far harder to read and in my case, I didn't realize that it was related to my question. I guess that if someone encounters the same situation I had, he might just go to this answer and skip it because harder to read. That's why I added this question